# WKWebView takeSnapshot without scrollbars macOS

Tags: macos, svg, wkwebview

Trying to render SVG file using `WKWebView`. However the scrollBars are displayed in resulting snapshot.
According to
[WebKit implementation](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/8cb23c3aba4625992c17a26a75e7631db9577bfb/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebView.mm) there is private method `_setMinimumLayoutWidth:` which will disable the scrollability of document. The solution works but it's private method.

Looking for a way to takeSnapshot without scrollbars

PS: old WebView doesn't have this problem as I can easily modify scrollView. 10.16 has createPDF which doesn't have problem neither with background nor scrollers

```
  override init() {
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    //webView.setValue(false, forKey: "alwaysShowsVerticalScroller") //doesn't work + private
    //webView.setValue(false, forKey: "alwaysShowsHorizontalScroller") //doesn't work + private
    //webView.perform(selector, with: NSNumber(value: 500.0))
    webView.setValue(500.0, forKey: "minimumLayoutWidth") //works but private
    webView.setValue(false, forKey: "draws" + "background".capitalized) //works but private
    super.init()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
 }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  
  //...some code to resize 
  webView.setFrameSize(NSMakeSize(svgNodeWidth * zoomFactor + offset , svgNodeHeight * zoomFactor + offset))

  let configuration = WKSnapshotConfiguration()
  webView.takeSnapshot(with: configuration) { (image, error) in

      //resulting image will show empty area for horizontal and vertical scrollbar
      if let error = error {
          debugPrint(error)
      }
      self.completion?(image)
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="10" height="10" fill="purple" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- With a width of 0 or less, nothing will be rendered -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="purple"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem only appeared on macOS ~10.15.3. It's not present on 10.13/10.14/11.0. Extra padding will solve the issue.

```
let padding : CGFloat = 50

func adjustSizeAndMagnify() {
    if svgNodeWidth > 0 && svgNodeHeight > 0 {
         zoomFactor = [minimumWidth / svgNodeWidth, minimumHeight / svgNodeHeight].max() ?? 1
         let backingScale = NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor ?? 1
         zoomFactor = zoomFactor / backingScale
         webView.setFrameSize(NSMakeSize(svgNodeWidth * zoomFactor + padding , svgNodeHeight * zoomFactor + padding))
         webView.magnification = zoomFactor
     }
}

func takeSnapshot() {
    adjustSizeAndMagnify()
    let configuration = WKSnapshotConfiguration()
    configuration.rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, webView.frame.size.width - padding, webView.frame.size.height - padding)
    webView.takeSnapshot(with: configuration) { (image, error) in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
        self.completion?(image)
    }
}
```